# We should reassign [tag:non-linear-dynamics] to [tag:complex-systems]

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

I propose we make the tag [non-linear-dynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-linear-dynamics) a synonym of [complex-systems](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-systems).

Currently, [non-linear-dynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-linear-dynamics) is set as a synonym of [non-linear-systems](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-linear-systems), but I'd like to argue that the most common usage of the term *nonlinear dynamics* is in the sense of being the (nonlinear) dynamics of [dynamical-systems](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamical-systems) and it should, just as the latter, be considered a synonym of [complex-systems](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-systems):

- The common understanding of the subject, as described, e.g., by the [the journal Nature](https://www.nature.com/subjects/nonlinear-dynamics), is:

  > Nonlinear dynamics is the branch of physics that studies systems governed by equations more complex than the linear, aX+b form. Nonlinear systems, such as the weather or neurons, often appear chaotic, unpredictable or counterintuitive, and yet their behaviour is not random.

  which **isn't** expressed by the current description of the [nonlinear systems tag](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/non-linear-systems/info):

  > The term non-linear or nonlinear has several definitions but is generally used to describe a system that cannot be approximated by a superposition principle or perturbative approach.
- The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_system) for Complex Systems lists "Nonlinear dynamics" among its topics.
- Research institutions around the world clearly consider *nonlinear dynamics* as a subject in the context of *complex systems*. For instance (research group name, followed by keywords):

  - [Manchester Centre for Nonlinear Dynamics](http://www.mcnd.manchester.ac.uk/pictures.php)
    granular media, fluid dynamics, turbulence, chaos
  - [Center for Nonlinear Dynamics (UT - Austin)](http://chaos.utexas.edu/)
    fluid dynamics, granular matter, social dynamics
  - [Institute for Nonlinear Dynamics (Göttingen)](http://www.uni-goettingen.de/en/433694.html)
    pattern formation, fluid dynamics, neurophysics, networks
  - [Nonlinear Dynamics, Chaos and Complex Systems (U. Maryland)](https://umdphysics.umd.edu/research/research-areas/nonlinear-dynamics-chaos-and-complex-systems.html)
    chaos, granular dynamics, pattern formation, networks
  - [Nonlinear Dynamics (U. Bayreuth)](https://www.uni-bayreuth.de/en/research/focus-areas/advanced-fields/7_nonlinear_dynamics/index.html)
    complex fluids, soft matter, geoecology, chaos
  - [Nonlinear Dynamics Group (U. Kyoto)](http://www.ton.scphys.kyoto-u.ac.jp/nonlinear-old2/english/research.html)
    statistical physics, structure formation, patterns, neuronal systems
  - [Nonlinear Physics Group (Tokyo M. U.)](http://www.comp.tmu.ac.jp/nonlinear/en/research.html)
    chaos, Hamiltonian systems, quantum chaos
  - [Nonlinear and Complex Systems Laboratory at POSTECH (Korea)](https://dsweb.siam.org/The-Magazine/Article/nonlinear-and-complex-systems-laboratory-at-postech-korea)
    pattern formation, self-organization, chaos, brain science
  - [Oscillations Control Group (U. of São Paulo)](http://portal.if.usp.br/controle/)
    turbulence, chaos, complex systems, networks

Comment: Frankly, the term "nonlinear system" doesn't make any sense to me at all. And its tag wiki is pretty bad, too ─ that's not what nonperturbative means, and there's plenty of nonlinear perturbative dynamics out there.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I agree, I also don't like it. Even "nonlinear dynamics" is not that great, that's another reason I like Qmechanic suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

One suggestion would be to create an umbrella tag [non-linear-and-complex-systems](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-linear-and-complex-systems). Would that be an improvement?

Comment: Yes, I think that would capture it very well.

Comment: Is the little attention this question is receiving an impediment to the change being implemented? It would be great to have your suggestion put in practice.

Comment: If there are no serious protests or counterproposals, it will be implemented eventually.